# How to get records from two Dates in MySql if stored in String Format?

Tags: mysql

If you store your dates in string format in mySql.How to get the Records

Answer (score 1):

You take the wrong way.
You should store the date in date format, not in string

Answer (score 0):

Using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to get the result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE([dateFieldName], '%d|%m|%Y')
      BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01|01|2016','%d|%m|%Y') AND 
              STR_TO_DATE('31|12|2016','%d|%m|%Y')
```

Comment: This one will get worse and worse the bigger your database grows.

Comment: it is not the right way to store date. Moreover you can not index them properly.